# Local Notification on watchOS 3 not showed

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, watchos-3, unnotificationrequest

I’ve a problem with the UNNotification on watchOS 3 !

In watchOS 2 and iOS 9 to schedule a local notification I use WatchConnectivity 
From watch I send a message to iPhone and the iPhone schedule the local notification 
When the notification arrive with the iPhone locked the watch duplicate the notification and NotificationController in WatchKit Extension call the method

```
- (void)didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler;
```

that show the notification on watch.

So in watchOS 3 i would like send and receive the notification directly from watch
some code

In watchKit Extension Target i add UserNotifications.framework 
[image]

In ExtensionDelegate import the framework, add the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and request the authorization

```
#import "ExtensionDelegate.h"
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface ExtensionDelegate()<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>{
}
@end

@implementation ExtensionDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    // Perform any final initialization of your application.

    UNUserNotificationCenter *notifCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    notifCenter.delegate = self;

    [notifCenter requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){

        if( !error ){
            // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
        }
    }];

}
```

Then in InterfaceController i schedule UNNotification

```
- (IBAction)SendLocalNotification {

    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“Test” arguments:nil];
    content.subtitle = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“Local notification from Watch " arguments:nil];
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    [content setValue:@YES forKeyPath:@"shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground"];

    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* timeTrigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                                      triggerWithTimeInterval:10 repeats:NO];

    NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:uuid
                                                                          content:content trigger:timeTrigger];

    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@" local notification scheduled”);
        }
    }];

}
```

(I've also update SendLocalNotification method after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937385/local-notification-in-watchos-3), but I 've not solved the problem)

in NotificationController import the framework and this is the code

```
#import "NotificationController.h"

#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface NotificationController()

@end


@implementation NotificationController
@synthesize label;

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        // Initialize variables here.
        // Configure interface objects here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];
}

- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    [super didDeactivate];
}


- (void)didReceiveNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
                withCompletion:(void(^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType interface)) completionHandler {
    // This method is called when a notification needs to be presented.
    // Implement it if you use a dynamic notification interface.
    // Populate your dynamic notification interface as quickly as possible.
    //
    // After populating your dynamic notification interface call the completion block.

    [label setText:notification.request.content.subtitle];
    completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
}


@end
```

In ExtensionDelegate i also implement the method to receive the notification when the app is in foreground

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@“notification arrived in foreground");

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert|UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
}
```

It’s seem everything ok but ….

-when the watch app is in background don’t receive the notification

-when the watch app is in foreground the console print the log

```
notification arrived in foreground
```

but  the notification isn’t shown

Where is the problem ?
What i’ve missed ?

I hope someone can help me !!

Thank you so much in advance !!

Vanni